# How to use Chrome Workspaces to save CSS changed locally with Angular2 + webpack?

Tags: css, google-chrome, angular, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 app with Webpack and webpack-dev-server.

Usually I use the Google Chrome dev tools feature "workspaces" to directly edit CSS files locally, so I can make permanent style changes to local CSS files.

Is it possible to so the same with Webpack ? I.e. define sourcemap and have Chrome write directly to the CSS files ?

I don't mind not concatenating the CSS files and use them as-is for this purpose.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Read the [Webpack your Chrome DevTools Workspaces](https://medium.com/@rafaelideleon/webpack-your-chrome-devtools-workspaces-cb9cca8d50da#.j2fcl5uwx) article for a detailed walkthrough of configuring your webpack config.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to do this in Angular 6/7 without ejecting the app ? thx